SQL weekending date calculation
I have a set of data which has some dates of the week. I need to extract the next Friday date from the data and if the date is already on Friday then print the same date. I have tried multiple sources but one or the other error comes. I need to output on snowflake.
If the date is 30-04-2024 then the output I need is 03-05-2024 (which is next Friday) and if the date is already 03-05-2024 then return the same date ( as it is already on Friday).

What is the data type of the column that contains the value 30-04-2024 ? Is it DATE ?

If its monday then add 4 days, if tuesday then 3 days and so on.

I have never used snowflake but looking at the documentation, I propose a combination of dayname, dateadd and case.
I don't know if the following is legal [SQL] syntax for snowflake and I have not found a way to test the below SQL, nonetheless:
(Note that the below assumes that column has type DATE.)
select DATEADD(day,
               case DAYNAME(column)
                   when 'Sat' then 6
                   when 'Sun' then 5
                   when 'Mon' then 4
                   when 'Tue' then 3
                   when 'Wed' then 2
                   when 'Thu' then 1
                   else 0
               end,
               column) as FRIDAY
from table


you can try using Next_day and DayName function as  follow
SELECT CURRENT_DATE() AS "Today's Date",  
NEXT_DAY("Today's Date", 'Friday ') AS "Next Friday"
,DAYNAME( CURRENT_DATE()) ,
case when DAYNAME( CURRENT_DATE()) = 'Fri' Then DAYNAME( CURRENT_DATE())
else NEXT_DAY("Today's Date", 'Friday ')  END next_friday
;


You can just shift your date by a day before looking for the next Friday so it lands either on the Friday it's already on, or the next Friday
select next_day('2024-04-05'::date-1,'Friday');

select next_day('2024-04-03'::date-1,'Friday');

